# The Site Can't Be Reach Even Host Is '0.0.0.0' (flask,python)

Tags: python, flask

So, I just made a simple script like this

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=3000)
```

I am using my campus network. This is my IP configuration after connect to my campus WiFi

[image: My IP Configuration Connected to My Campus WiFi]

But, when I'm trying to open 10.10.228.169:3000 from another laptop that also connect to the same WiFi, "This Site Can't Be Reach" is shown. But, if i try to open it in my laptop that run that script, it worked. Can you tell me what's wrong here? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your network does not have port blocking enabled. A few firewalls (Fortinet for example) blocks certain ports. Try running the same script on port 80.

Comment: I think the problem is the network because when I connected to my own WiFi router it's working. So, is there any special configuration to my connection to my campus WiFi based on my IP configuration?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I mentioned earlier. Your college campus firewall is probably blocking the port on which you are running your app. Test it on your campus WiFi after running this on port 80 (would be open most probably)